# Can I share an updating podcast archive via torrent file?

Tags: backup, bittorrent, archiving, podcasts

Given the case I produce podcasts, and my followers want to have the full collection on local storage: I would create a torrent file for the folder with all the audio files.

Now can I add new podcast files to the folder, so my followers (running a torrent client) can automatically download it to their hard disk - via the same old torrent file?

Comment: I am asking here because I was sent to superuser from stackoverflow  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45249945/4287572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now can I add new podcast files to the folder, so my followers (running a torrent client) can automatically download it to their hard disk - via the same old torrent file?

No, that's not possible with BitTorrent.

A better solution would be to use the proprietary program [Resilio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/) (formerly BitTorrent Sync).
or the open source project [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/).

Comment: Thank you so much. [Resilio Sync & Syncthing](https://hulbee.com/video?query=%20resilio%20sync%20syncthing) seem to be the right solution.